# Accessing ViewModel properties in parent ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, viewmodel

I'm using this technique for navigation between views: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30898.simple-navigation-technique-in-wpf-using-mvvm.aspx

I have the main ViewModel with menu buttons bound to SelectedViewModel property change commands:

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public ICommand SomeViewCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand OtherViewCommand { get; set; }
    private object selectedViewModel;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public object SelectedViewModel
    {
        get { return selectedViewModel; }
        set { selectedViewModel = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel"); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand<object, object>(null, (object o) => OpenSomeView());
        OtherViewCommand = new RelayCommand<object, object>(null, (object o) => OpenOtherView());
    }

    private void OpenSomeView()
    {
       SelectedViewModel = new SomeViewModel();
    }

    private void OpenOtherView(object obj)
    {
       if(SelectedViewModel != null && SelectedViewModel.GetType() == typeof(SomeViewModel))
       {
          SomeViewModel s = (SomeViewModel)SelectedViewModel;

          // always 0
          if (s.NumberOfChanges > 0)
          {
             MessageBox.Show("test", "Error");
          }

          // SelectedViewModel = new OtherViewModel(); after confirmation dialog
       }
       else
          SelectedViewModel = new OtherViewModel();
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }

}
```

If I'm in SomeView, I'd like to check its property (number of changes) before switching to OtherView and show a confirmation dialog to the user to confirm their action. I need the current value, but any property seems to have its initialization value. Why?

What would be the cleanest way of doing this? I know it can be done by making the property static, but that seems dirty to me.

Comment: I guess the `CurrentViewModel` in `OpenOtherView` should be `SelectedViewModel`? Also are you sure the `NumberOfChanges` actually changes in `SomeViewModel`?

Comment: It is indeed, I shortened the code so that it only shows what's needed and renamed this for some reason, corrected. And yes, I'm sure, within the child ViewModel the value is correct.

Comment: The code you posted should work from what I can tell, so I suspect the issue to be within the child ViewModel. If you only need the number of changes, counting those in the parent ViewModel through `PropertyChanged` event of the child like Satish suggests should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

In OnPropertyChanged method you can set NumberOfChanges.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, could you show a short example?

Comment: `private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
 {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
         s.NumberOfChanges++;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
`
Something like above. Because on change of any property it will enter this method. You can increment there. Correct me if i am wrong